# Hive jdbc driver not appearing in Pentaho Kettle create new connection

Tags: hive, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Can someone suggest how to integrate Hive plugin to create a hive database connection in Pentaho Spoon , so that i can fetch the tables and data from the Hive tables and apply transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps

- Open the job
- Right Click on Database Connection
- Click the General Tab
- Select Hadoop Hive or Hadoop Hive 2 as the Connection Type
- Fill in the Hostname, DatabaseName, PortNumber and credentials

Comment: or add a generic connection and type the url as jdbc:hive2://(...)